# Copy & Paste the data from Excel to Datatable using JSF (Primefaces)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

i want to Copy & Paste the data from Excel to Datatable using JSF (Primefaces). please suggest me a possibilities to achieve copy & paste.

Comment: let us know if you got something.

Comment: Do you want to import from an Excel sheet to a datatable programmatically or copy & paste yourself manually?

Comment: I want to copy & paste into datatable manually.

Comment: if i copy data of Excel file and past it into text file, than their is no separate to identified for column than how i can break it into datatable? Beacuse i am thinking to write javascript to take text of pasted text area and convert it into data table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can listen to a paste event of dataTable primefaces object and get the clipboard data from the event object, format the data to a JSONobject (in the example I used a JSONArray) to send it via remoteCommand to a backingBean.

xhtml:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="updateData" process="@this" action="#{backingBean.updateData()}" update="dt" />

<p:dataTable widgetVar="dt" id="dt" value="#{backingBean.data}" var="d">
    <p:column headerText="column 1">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{d.col1}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="column 2">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{d.col2}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>

<h:outputScript>
    $(function(){
        PF('dt').jq.on("paste", function(e){
            var data = e.originalEvent.clipboardData;
            var table = [];
            if(data &amp;&amp; data.items &amp;&amp; data.items[0]) {

                data.items[0].getAsString(function(text){

                    $.each( text.split("\n"), function(i, r){
                        table[i] = r.split("\t");
                    });

                    updateData([{name: 'data', value: JSON.stringify(table) }]);
                });
            }
        });

    });
</h:outputScript>
```

In your remoteCommand action decode the JSON data and populate the dataTable data provider. Table data is only a Java object with 2 properties (col1 and col2).

BackingBean:

```
private List<TableData> data;

public List<TableData> getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(List<TableData> data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void updateData(){
    Map<String, String> paramValues = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String json = paramValues.get("data");
    JSONArray table = new JSONArray(json);
    data = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < table.length(); i++){
        JSONArray row = table.getJSONArray(i);
        TableData t = new TableData();

        for (int j = 0; j < row.length(); j++ ){
            String o = row.getString(j);
            if (j == 0){
                t.setCol1(o);
            } else {
                t.setCol2(o);
            }
        }

        data.add(t);

    }
}
```

This is only an example, an hint, it needs more work to work properly. Maybe you need a custom primefaces object to do so or extend the PF dataTable.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code.i'll try above approach and update the staus. Thanks again.